# How to return the SelectList from SelectListItem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Working with DropdownList in mvc4. I need to return a selectlist to bind the dropdown on edit, but I am getting an error `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>"`. So kindly help me to convert to SelectList

code:

```
    public List<SelectList> SelectDoctoronEdit(int id)
    {

        Gema_Doctor[] doctorList;
        doctorList = gema_Doctor.GetDoctor().ToArray();
        List<Gema_Doctor> listDoctor = new List<Gema_Doctor>(doctorList);
        List<SelectListItem> dropItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        RDM_Patient patientsSelect = rdm_Patient.GetPatient().First(c => c.PatientID == id);
        dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "" });
        foreach (Gema_Doctor doctorValues in listDoctor)
        {
            RDM_Patient patients = rdm_Patient.GetPatient().First(c => c.PatientID == id);
            if (patients.DoctorID == doctorValues.Dr_Id)
            {
                dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = doctorValues.Dr_Name, Value = doctorValues.Dr_Id.ToString(), Selected = true });
            }
            else
            {
                dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = doctorValues.Dr_Name, Value = doctorValues.Dr_Id.ToString(), Selected = false });

            }


        }
        //return dropItems; 

        SelectList s1 = new SelectList(dropItems, "Value", "Text", patientsSelect.DoctorID);
        return s1;


    }   



View Page:

    <tr>
           <td>
             @Html.LabelFor(M => Model.Patient.City)
             @Html.TextBoxFor(M => Model.Patient.City)

           </td>
           <td>
             @Html.LabelFor(M => Model.Patient.Add1)
             @Html.TextBoxFor(M => Model.Patient.Add1)


           </td>
           <td>
             @Html.LabelFor(M => Model.Patient.Add2)
             @Html.TextBoxFor(M => Model.Patient.Add2)

           </td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
          <td>

           </td>
           <td>
            @Html.Label("Doctor")

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Patient.DoctorID.ToString(), (SelectList)ViewBag.doctorType)


           </td>
           <td>

           </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change return type of your method from:

`public List<SelectList> SelectDoctoronEdit(int id)`

to

`public SelectList SelectDoctoronEdit(int id)`

You are trying to return `s1` variable that is `typeOf SelectList` and your method signature expects you to return List of SelectList items.

PS. You can't use functions inside lambda expression

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Patient.DoctorID.ToString(), (SelectList)ViewBag.doctorType)
```

Error is because of **Model.Patient.DoctorID.ToString()**

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Patient.DoctorID, (SelectList)ViewBag.doctorType)
```

You are creating *DropDownList* for property in your model, you don't need to use *ToString()* method there.

Comment: I am getting Error in ViewPage "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions ". Already i have posted my view page also in above question

Answer (score 1):

Your method should return `List<SelectListItem>` instead of `List<SelectList>`:

```
public List<SelectListItem> SelectDoctoronEdit(int id)
{
    Gema_Doctor[] doctorList;
    doctorList = gema_Doctor.GetDoctor().ToArray();
    List<Gema_Doctor> listDoctor = new List<Gema_Doctor>(doctorList);
    List<SelectListItem> dropItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    RDM_Patient patientsSelect = rdm_Patient.GetPatient().First(c => c.PatientID == id);
    dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "" });
    foreach (Gema_Doctor doctorValues in listDoctor)
    {
        RDM_Patient patients = rdm_Patient.GetPatient().First(c => c.PatientID == id);
        if (patients.DoctorID == doctorValues.Dr_Id)
        {
            dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = doctorValues.Dr_Name, Value = doctorValues.Dr_Id.ToString(), Selected = true });
        }
        else
        {
            dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = doctorValues.Dr_Name, Value = doctorValues.Dr_Id.ToString(), Selected = false });

        }
    }

    return new SelectList(dropItems, "Value", "Text", patientsSelect.DoctorID);
}
```

or if you prefer a `SelectList` directly:

```
public SelectList SelectDoctoronEdit(int id)
{
    Gema_Doctor[] doctorList;
    doctorList = gema_Doctor.GetDoctor().ToArray();
    List<Gema_Doctor> listDoctor = new List<Gema_Doctor>(doctorList);
    List<SelectListItem> dropItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    RDM_Patient patientsSelect = rdm_Patient.GetPatient().First(c => c.PatientID == id);
    dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "" });
    foreach (Gema_Doctor doctorValues in listDoctor)
    {
        RDM_Patient patients = rdm_Patient.GetPatient().First(c => c.PatientID == id);
        if (patients.DoctorID == doctorValues.Dr_Id)
        {
            dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = doctorValues.Dr_Name, Value = doctorValues.Dr_Id.ToString(), Selected = true });
        }
        else
        {
            dropItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = doctorValues.Dr_Name, Value = doctorValues.Dr_Id.ToString(), Selected = false });

        }
    }

    return dropItems;
}
```

Comment: My View Page Needs SelectList . My view page is  @Html.Label("Doctor")

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Patient.DoctorID.ToString(), (SelectList)ViewBag.doctorType)

Comment: `SelectList` implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so you could pretty easily use one or the other.